# PowerDNS error 400 when trying to add domain

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, powerdns

I am currently trying to setup powerDNS with mysql as backend and powerDNS Admin. I was able to login in powerDNS Admin and can edit user and change settings. However upon trying to add a domain, it shows error 400.

I tried capturing the error from the logs and it said Unauthorized. Tried also running `GET` using Postman from the api and it shows the same Unauthorized message.

I'm a noob in linux and powerdns and any suggestions/help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the powerDNS admin privileges you have.

Comment: @danblack Administrator

Answer (score 0):

Show log powerdns from powerdns services

`sudo systemctl status pdns`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34588371)